# How to run Angular 2 form IntelliJ using Tomcat?

Tags: macos, tomcat, intellij-idea, angular, typescript

I'm writing an Angular 2 code in a project that is hosted by a Tomcat. I now add some Angular 2 code.

I used the [quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) project which uses realtime-watch compiler. Meaning it compiles the `ts` files when a change is detected.

However, now all the project is hosted by the Tomcat. So, how do I compile the `ts` files? Manually?

Press `build project` for every code change?

I see `package.json` includes this:

```
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
```

But when I run

```
➜  angular2 git:(push_n) ✗ npm tsc:w

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, edit, explore, get,
    help, help-search, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,
    list, ln, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars,
    start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view, whoami
```

**Update**

I followed Supun's instructions

and now I get:

```
➜ tsc -w /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/*

error TS6053: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/app.ts' not found.
error TS6053: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/node_modules.ts' not found.
error TS6053: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/typings.ts' not found.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/index.html' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/pushResult.html' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/styles.css' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/systemjs.config.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/tsconfig.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6054: File '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/typings.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
11:45:17 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

But i change files, and no logs appear in the console

Comment: What if you use a build tool like Gulp or Grunt??

Comment: why is `npm tsc:w` not recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following these steps should be fine,

- Install tscw globally using terminal or command-prompt in windows (from anywhere)-> **npm install -g tscw**
- Then, type **tsc** (only 'tsc' - no need 'npm tsc' or ) on the command prompt, and verify output. You should get something like this.

[image]

- Now you can do what you want from the set of listed operations and you can include parameters if any.

Comment: but then, how can i run the `compile when changes`?

Comment: the last listed command, '-w --watch'   -> watch input files.

Comment: how can i name a folder and all files in it?

Comment: I did this: `tsc -w /Users/elad/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/angular2/*` but yet changing some files showed nothing in the console log

Comment: @EladBenda so you suggest that for some .ts files its ok, but not working for some other files, right? Or for same file, it is working sometime and not working in some other occasions? or both? It is somewhat difficult to answer that without reproducing the issue. Anyway the general rule is, 'watch' is supposed to compile for any changes in .ts. But there are situations that it is not happening as expected. Ex: (1) Loading some new resource files needs to restart server. (2) Some framework specific operations needs to  restart the server. (3) Your changes needs some methods like onStart(). etc